# how to use permission_send Manifest android inside subclass?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

I made an application using the tab navigation in android studio. On one of the tabs I want to make an SMS sending feature. I've added permissions to AndroidManifest.xml but the feature still won't work

This is My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.melani.dprdbkt">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
          android:name=".SendSMSActivity"
          android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />


  </application>
</manifest>
```

This is My MainActivity.java

```
package com.melani.dprdbkt;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabItem;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;
    TabItem tabHome;
    TabItem tabBerita;
    TabItem tabAgenda;
    TabItem tabAnggota;
    TabItem tabLink;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabHome = findViewById(R.id.tabHome);
        tabBerita = findViewById(R.id.tabBerita);
        tabAgenda = findViewById(R.id.tabAgenda);
        tabAnggota = findViewById(R.id.tabAnggota);
        tabLink = findViewById(R.id.tabLink);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);


        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorHome));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorHome));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorHome));
                    }
                } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorBerita));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorBerita));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorBerita));
                    }
                }
                else if (tab.getPosition() == 3) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorAgenda));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorAgenda));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorAgenda));
                    }
                } else if (tab.getPosition() == 4) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorAnggota));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorAnggota));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorAnggota));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorLink));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                            R.color.colorLink));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,
                                R.color.colorLink));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    }
}
```

Send SMSActivity.java

```
package com.melani.dprdbkt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendSMSActivity extends MainActivity {
private  static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS=0;
    private EditText txtMobile;
    private EditText txtMessage;
    private Button btnSms;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_link);
        txtMobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);
        btnSms = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        btnSms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    SmsManager smgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smgr.sendTextMessage(txtMobile.getText().toString(),null,txtMessage.getText().toString(),null,null);
                    Toast.makeText(SendSMSActivity.this, "SMS Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(SendSMSActivity.this, "SMS Failed to Send, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

linkFragment.java

```
package com.melani.dprdbkt;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import android.app.m

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LinkFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_link, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_link, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_link) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

fragment_link.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.melani.dprdbkt.LinkFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="63dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Ke : "

        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhoneNo"
        android:layout_width="337dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:phoneNumber="true"></EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSMS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="Pesan : "
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSMS"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"

        android:text="Send" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android.permission.SEND_SMS` is a dangerous permission, as in, its protection level is "dangerous". Dangerous permissions are not granted at install time, you have to request it and make sure it's been granted by the user before you can use any feature that requires this permission. Declaring them in manifest file is not enough.

Determining if a permission has been granted...

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
}
```

Requesting a permission...

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
            MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_SEND_SMS)
```

There's a whole section in [Android Developer Guides](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) explaning in details how permissions work and how to request them